# Dust and wax buildup on hardwood floor

Tags: hardwood-floor, dust

My wife hired a maid who applied orange-glo to our hardwood floors, but without dusting first (she's not with us anymore).  Unfortunately, there are now many areas of the floor where the multiple coatings over dust piled up and caused a gray-colored patch appearance -- it almost looks as if the wood is worn out and discolored, however, it's the dust covered with dried up orange-glo.

Is there a safe solvent (not CC4 or methyl-ethyl-ketone ;-) which will dissolve such a mess?

FYI - the current maid applies nothing to the flooring.

Comment: The manufacturers say [NOT FOR USE ON WOOD FLOORS](http://www.orangeglo.com/OrangeGlo.html) - but I think thats because it creates a slipping hazard.

Comment: Thanks - any recommendation on a solvent?